# Open Jquery accordion will not close when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

there are a 4 accordions on the page, currently the open accordion only closes when you click on another accordion. I need to also close when you click on it. Here's the code I used.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var accordionEntries = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-entry');
  var accordionImages = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-image');

  for (var i = 0; i < accordionEntries.length; i++) {
    accordionEntries[i].dataset.target = 'accordion-image-' + i;
    accordionImages[i].classList.add('accordion-image-' + i);
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.accordion-header', function() {
    $('.accordion-open').removeClass('accordion-open')
    var parent = $(this).closest('.accordion-entry');
    parent.addClass('accordion-open');
    $('.' + parent.data('target')).addClass('accordion-open')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m however it does not seem to work. where in my code should I add it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by:

```
$('.accordion-open').removeClass('accordion-open')
```

which closes all accordion panels including the one you click on, then (re)opens the current one.

If you want to "toggle" the accordion panel, you need to check if the current panel is open first, then close it, then do nothing.

This can be achieved with:

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-header', function() {
    if ($(this).is(".accordion-open")) {
        $(this).removeClass("accordion-open");
        return;
    }
    ...
```